# add minus count and submit data in array

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, dynamic-arrays

I got problem to add minus count in array. when I try to plus or minus no value display. The issue appear when I using array method. Sorry, I'm new to array method. Could you all show me where is my fault code. This my demo code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-angular-8-start-template-q7m3fj)

HTML

```
<div class="p-buttom">
    <ion-button expand="full" color="dark" (click)="add()">Add</ion-button>
</div>
    <div class="size-bg" *ngFor="let num of size;let i = index">
    <span style="display: flex;">
        <ion-col>
            <ion-item lines="none" size="6" class="border">
                <ion-label position="stacked">weight</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" class="uppercase" [(ngModel)]="data.weight[i]" name="menuCode"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-item lines="none" size="6" class="border">
                <ion-label position="stacked">Price</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" class="uppercase" [(ngModel)]="data.price[i]" name="menuCode"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
    </span>
    <ion-label style="color: black; ">quantity</ion-label>
    <ion-col size="12">
        <div class="add-quatity">
            <ion-button class="removeBtn no-padding " fill="solid " slot="end" style="color: black;" (click)="MinusMinOrder() ">
               -
            </ion-button>
            <ion-input class="itemCount no-padding" name="quantity" (keypress)="numberOnlyValidation($event)" [(ngModel)]="data.quantity[i]" value="{{addQuantityP[i]}}"></ion-input>
            <ion-button class="addBtn no-padding " fill="solid " slot="end" style="color: black;" (click)="addQuantity(i) ">
                +
            </ion-button>
        </div>
    </ion-col>
    <div>
        <ion-button expand="full" color="danger" *ngIf="i >0" (click)="remove(i)">Delete</ion-button>
    </div>
    </div>
<div>
  <ion-button fill="solid " slot="end" (click)="addMenu() ">Submit</ion-button> 
</div>
```

Component

```
add(){
    this.size.push('');
  }

  remove(index) {
    this.size.splice(index,1)
  }
  minusQuantity(i){
    console.log(i);
    this.data.quantity[i]--;
    console.log(this.data.quantity[i]--);
  }
  addQuantity(i){
    console.log(i);
    this.data.quantity[i]++;
    console.log(this.data.quantity[i]++);
  }
addMenu(){
  console.log(this.data);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue in your code. If you want to add dynamically create array then you need to initialize default values of array of object.

like

```
size = [];
```

this is the resultant array you need to finalize. You have a UI data which the object has some properties.

like

```
{ weight: 0,
  quantity: 0,
  price: 0,
 }
```

Now your object is ready to push into the size array.

when you click on

```
add() {
 this.size.push({ weight: 0,
  quantity: 0,
  price: 0,
 });
}
```

function, Just push this object every time. In angular UI new object with new values will create. No need to worry about any other complex logic.

I'm providing you a full solution. you can add multiple items at the same time I test it. If you need any help from my site just let me know. thank
this is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-angular-8-start-template-qmjzdn?file=src/app/tab1/tab1.page.ts) of solution.

cheers.

Comment: Most welcome. I'm really happy to help you. thanks

Comment: Link only answers are not good for community. You have to explain what was wrong with OPs approach, what were the mistakes and should provide an opportunity to learn instead of providing complete solution.

Comment: Thanks @Anand G. Next time I'll answer with full detail and code.

Answer (score 1):

You code has certain issues.

1. The way you are collecting the data is not going to work when you will add nested rows.
2. The method name to minus the quantity is incorrect.
3. You added `[(ngModel)]="data.quantity[i]"` which is unnecessary since you are not doing any two way binding of data.

I have fixed your code and highlighted the changes with comments. You can check the changes at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-angular-8-start-template-aih1cm?file=src/app/tab1/tab1.page.html)

```js
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {
  size = [];
  // Changing the data structure to map nested rows
  data = [{
    weight: 0,
    price: 0,
    quantity: 0
  }]

  constructor() {}

  add() {
    this.size.push('');
  }

  remove(index) {
    this.size.splice(index, 1)
  }

  minusQuantity(i) {
    //Stop reducing quantity after 0
    this.data[i].quantity = this.data[i].quantity != 0 ? this.data[i].quantity - 1 : 0
  }

  addQuantity(i) {
    this.data[i].quantity = this.data[i].quantity + 1
  }
  addMenu() {
    console.log(this.data);
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      My app
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
   <div class="p-buttom">
        <ion-button expand="full" color="dark" (click)="add()">Add</ion-button>
    </div>
        <div class="size-bg" *ngFor="let num of size;let i = index">
        <span style="display: flex;">
            <ion-col>
                <ion-item lines="none" size="6" class="border">
                    <ion-label position="stacked">weight</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" class="uppercase" [(ngModel)]="data[i].weight" name="menuCode"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
                <ion-item lines="none" size="6" class="border">
                    <ion-label position="stacked">Price</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" class="uppercase" [(ngModel)]="data[i].price" name="menuCode"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
        </span>
        <ion-label style="color: black; ">quantity</ion-label>
        <ion-col size="12">
            <div class="add-quatity">
                <ion-button class="removeBtn no-padding " fill="solid " slot="end" style="color: black;" (click)="minusQuantity(i) ">
                   -
                </ion-button>
                <ion-input class="itemCount no-padding" name="quantity" (keypress)="numberOnlyValidation($event)" value="{{data[i].quantity}}"></ion-input>
                <ion-button class="addBtn no-padding " fill="solid " slot="end" style="color: black;" (click)="addQuantity(i) ">
                    +
                </ion-button>
            </div>
        </ion-col>
        <div>
            <ion-button expand="full" color="danger" *ngIf="i >0" (click)="remove(i)">Delete</ion-button>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div>
      <ion-button fill="solid " slot="end" (click)="addMenu() ">Submit</ion-button> 
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It working when I click ADD button once. But when I click ADD button more than once, Plus Quantity on second list not working and then when I submit only first list array data submit and second list not submit

Comment: I set the same issue you mententioned. @Fash. I share my code with you wait.